# How large this subset is to say that it should equal the group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $\alpha$ be a continuous automorphism on a compact group $G$ with normalized Haar measure $m$. We may say $\alpha$ is $n$-splitting, if the set 
$$\text{Spl}_n(\alpha):=\left\{g\in G: \prod_{k=1}^ng^{\alpha^{n-k}}=1\right\}$$
has a positive Haar measure.Does there exist a positive number $0<r<1$, such that $m(\text{Spl}_n(\alpha))\geq r$ implies $\text{Spl}_n(\alpha)=G$?

Comment: In what context does this definition arise?  It looks like the sort of thing that might come up in the context of cohomology (my first thought is of Galois cohomology over a finite field) ….

Comment: @LSpice It is not a formal definition, but I faced that in the context of profinite groups.